# Handling screen orientation with ViewStubs

Tags: android, android-activity, screen-orientation, viewstub

Here is my problem.

I have a base activity that contains a view stub and in my sub activities, I inflate the activities layout in a ViewStub.

For instance, in base activity layout :

```
<ViewStub
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/activity_content"/>
```

ANd in my SubActivity1 :

```
public class SubActivity1 extends BaseActivity {
     @Override
     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        ViewStub viewStub = (ViewStub)  findViewById(R.id.activity_content);
        viewStub.setLayoutResource(R.layout.subactivity_layout);
        viewStub.inflate();
     }
}
```

My problem is when the screen orientation changes for `SubActivity1`, for instance from portrait to landscape, the views are stacked.

I thought since the screen orientation changes, the activity is destroyed and recreated.

I was thinking if there is a way to `deinflate` the viewstub but it's impossible.

How to properly handle screen orientation with view stubs?

Comment: I think `viewstubs` are helper view components and aren't designed to hold entire activitys' layouts.

Comment: Following up on @SQLiteNoob comment, is there a reason you aren't using Activity.setContentView?

Comment: Yes I am doing the setContentView in the BaseActivity.